# Taking values from data table rows and putting it in a cell as a list in R

Tags: r, list, data.table, apply, lapply

I am trying to put a list into each data table cell, where the list comes from the values of other columns. I don't want to enter the name of each column explicitly. Basically I want to redo the following working example without having to refer to V1, V2 explicitly:

```
# Create a data table as an example:
dat <- data.table(V1 = c(1:4), V2 = c('A','B','C','D'))
print(dat)
   V1 V2
1:  1  A
2:  2  B
3:  3  C
4:  4  D
```

Now I create a new variable V3 containing the list of the row values:

```
dat[, id := rownames(dat)] # Creating unique id per row
dat[, V3 := list(list(list(V1,V2))), by = 'id']
print(dat)
   V1 V2 id        V3
1:  1  A  1 <list[2]>
2:  2  B  2 <list[2]>
3:  3  C  3 <list[2]>
4:  4  D  4 <list[2]>
```

And we can see that the first element of V3 is correct and composed of the list 1,A:

```
unlist(dat$V3[[1]])
[1] "1" "A"
```

How can I make this process without having to explicitely list V1 and V2 (indeed in my code I have to do this for over 60 variables (i.e. taking a list from the rows across 60 variables), so I don't want to write list(list(list(V1, V2, V3, ..., V60)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply` -

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(V1 = c(1:4), V2 = c('A','B','C','D'))
dat[, V3 := apply(.SD, 1, as.list), .SDcols = V1:V2]
dat

#   V1 V2        V3
#1:  1  A <list[2]>
#2:  2  B <list[2]>
#3:  3  C <list[2]>
#4:  4  D <list[2]>

unlist(dat$V3[[1]])
# V1  V2 
#"1" "A"
```

If you need an unnamed vector use `unname(.SD)` in `apply`.

Answer (score 4):

i think this will do the trick

```
dat[, v3 := lapply(transpose(dat), as.list)]
#    V1 V2        v3
# 1:  1  A <list[2]>
# 2:  2  B <list[2]>
# 3:  3  C <list[2]>
# 4:  4  D <list[2]>

unlist(dat$v3[[1]])
#[1] "1" "A"
```

Comment: Your solution works but I accepted the other one since for my dataset, your solution takes 8.16 seconds, whereas the accepted answer takes 6.78 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` + `asplit` like below

```
> dat[, V3 := Map(as.list, asplit(.SD, 1))][]
   V1 V2        V3
1:  1  A <list[2]>
2:  2  B <list[2]>
3:  3  C <list[2]>
4:  4  D <list[2]>
```

Comment: NIce and concise

Comment: Great thanks! Again I'll accept the other answer as it is slightly faster :) But this answer is really nice as I didn't know how to use Map!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map` we could do

```
dat[, V3 := do.call(Map, c(f = function(x, y) as.list(c(x, y)), unname(.SD)))] 
dat
   V1 V2        V3
1:  1  A <list[2]>
2:  2  B <list[2]>
3:  3  C <list[2]>
4:  4  D <list[2]>
```